# Duplicate identifier readonly. (property) Constants.readonly : string in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, session-storage

I am using the below code in utils -> Constants.ts in my angular project.

**Constants.ts**

```
 export class Constants {
     static readonly LOCAL_STORAGE  = 'LOCAL_STORAGE';
     static readonly SESSSION_STORAGE  = 'SESSSION_STORAGE';
  }
```

I am getting the error: **Duplicate identifier readonly. (property) Constants.readonly : string.**  while i place my cursor on readonly.

And **[ts] '=' expected.
[ts] Cannot find name LOCAL_STORAGE any.** while i place my cursor on LOCAL_STORAGE.

So When i try to retrieve some data from session_storage in another ts file, like l**et mobileNo = this.db.get(Constants.SESSSION_STORAGE, Constants.MOBILE_NO);** I am facing the below error.

**property 'SESSION_STORAGE' does not exist on type 'typeOf Constants' any.**

Can anyone please help me on this error .

Comment: why not use an enum? you don’t need a class for this simple functionality

Comment: ah, sorry is this an angular or angularjs code snippet?

Comment: @ bodorgergely. this is angular 6 typescript

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to create a string enum.
TypeScript 2.4 Now has string enums so your code just works:

```
enum E {
    hello = "hello",
    world = "world"
};
```

Or for earlier versions of TypeScript:

```
export const Enum = createStringEnum(["Prop1", "Prop2"]);
export type Enum = keyof typeof Enum;

function createStringEnum<T extends string>(keys: T[]): {[K in T]: K} {
    return keys.reduce((res, key) => {
        res[key] = key;
        return res;
    }, Object.create(null));
}
```

createStringEnum returns an object with keys and values as strings passed in the array.

and `keyof typeof Enum;` is equivalent to "Prop1" | "Prop2".

This way, you can use Enum to both validate the type and access the string values inside the object.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `readonly` properties were introduced in version 2.0 of typescript.
Check that your installed typescript version is at least 2.0.

I have no problem using your class in a new stackblitz project.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-54596178